# retrieving fields with connect-busboy and node/express

Tags: node.js, forms, express

I am very new on node. I have been searching in google the last 3 days. I read the responses here and tried the solutions (when I understood them)
And I do not find/understand where is my error. I have the latest versionn of node/express and all modules, installed these last days (april 2015)
I have a simple form (css using getuikit)

```
extends layout
 block content
  <br>
  .uk-container
    form.uk-form-file(enctype="multipart/form-data")
      input.uk-hidden#what_to_do(type="text", name="what_to_do", value="load_files_disk")      
      button.uk-button Select a file
      input#upload-select-phys(type="file")
    br    
    if sessionFlash && sessionFlash.message
      div(class=sessionFlash.type)
        p <strong>FLASH!</strong> #{ sessionFlash.message }`
```

my routes.js has the get and post:

```
router.post('/load_files_disk',function(req, res) {
  var fstream;
  req.pipe(req.busboy);
   req.busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val) {
   console.log('Field [' + fieldname + ']: value: ' + inspect(val));
  });  // nothing, doesnot come here
   req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
        fstream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/../temp_files/' + filename);
        file.pipe(fstream);
        fstream.on('close', function () {
        });
    });
  req.busboy.on('finish', function() { 
     req.flash('success', 'This is a flash message');
     console.log('FLASH:' + req.flash('success')); // yes message OK
     res.redirect(303,'back');
  });
});
router.get('/load_file', function(req, res) {
        var d = new Date();
        console.log('date is + ', d.toUTCString());
        console.log('FLASH2:' + req.flash('success'));  // nothing!
    res.render('load_file', { user: req.user, sessionFlash: req.flash('success') });
});
```

I can load files without problem, but I never see the fields, nothing is written on the console, like it has not even entered that part of the code. 
What is wrong ? 
As you can see I would like also to send a flash message (which works in other part of my code without files) , but the req.flash is not passed. I do not know if both are connected or not.
Thank in advance for any hint you can provide - pat

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply loading these files in your browser, your router.js should be on your server, not on your client. I'd start by looking for a tutorial on Node (like  https://github.com/workshopper/learnyounode), and completing enough of it to be able to serve up an index.html. Then try to make requests from it.

This question is hard to answer without more context (looking at the rest of your serverside code?), but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you.But I believe my router.js is on my server side, all logging from that goes on the server log. Also I can upload files (and they go in the server). What surprises me is that I cannot get any information on fields , it is like if req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {..} is never "visited". there is an error somewhere in my code that prevents that, but I cannot find where.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the way UIkit parses  the form and sends that  to the server. The same code (form, routes etc), without all the UIkit stuff works perfectly. 
if somebody has done this and has a solution, I would be glad to know, for now I simplify my form and get it to work.